# Knockout.js: Pass current object to function from jQuery template

Tags: knockout.js

how to pass current object to function from template in knockout. here is code :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: people">
    <p>
     <b data-bind="click: $root.check, text : name"></b> 
     </p>
</div>



<div data-bind="template: 'peopleList'"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="peopleList">
    {{each people}}
        <p>
            <b data-bind="click: $root.check">${name}</b> is ${age} years old
        </p>
    {{/each}}
</script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="knock.js"></script>

<script>
var viewModel = function() {
       this.people = ko.observableArray([
            { name: 'Rod', age: 123 },
            { name: 'Jane', age: 125 },
        ]);
   this.check = function (val) {

            console.log('current value', val);
        }
}


    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());



</script>
```

if i click outside from template, check works as excpected, it prints current object, but if i click inside template check prints viewmodel object. why?  click : $root.check in first case prints e.x Object {name: "Jane", age: 125} and in second case inside template prints viewModel {}

Answer (score 1):

Since the actual `each` loop is performed by jQuery-templates and not by Knockout, the binding-context within the loop doesn't change.

You'll have to manually obtain it from jQuery-template and pass it to the function:

```
<b data-bind="click: $root.check.bind($value)">${name}</b> is ${age} years old
```

Answer (score 0):

okey i found solution, the problem is jquery.tmpl.min.js template engine...

Comment: Please, edit the answer and explain how you resolved the issue.